# How to pass spaces in table (specflow scenario)?

Tags: specflow

How to pass spaces in table ?

```
Background:
    Given the following books
        |Author         |(here several spaces)Title(here several spaces)|
```

Comment: Can you give some info as to why you're doing it?
Specflow naturally trims leading and trailing whitespace.
This is because people ignore the whitespace too when reading it.  Leading and trailing space only really "exists" for the computer - so it shouldn't affect behaviour driven human readable tests.

Comment: I want to test trimming of spaces in my site)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do this:

```
Given the following books
| Author              | Title               |
| "J. K. Rowling"     | "Harry P     "      |
| " Isaac Asimov   "  | "Robots and Empire" |
```

Then your bindings can be made to strip the quotes if present, but retaining the spaces.

I think this is much preferable to the idea of adding spaces afterward, because that isn't very human readable - quotations will make the spaces visible to the human (stakeholder / coder) reading them.

Answer (score 3):

You can work around it by adding an extra step. Something like:

```
Given the following books
|Author         | Title |
Add append <5> spaces to book title
```

Edit:

A complete feature can look something like:

```
Scenario: Adding books with spaces in the title
Given the following book
| price | title |
And <5> spaces appended to a title
When book is saved
Then the title should be equals to <title without spaces>
```

Comment: I think this is really bad practice. The point of SpecFlow tests is to make the tests readable for people who don't care about (or don't know about) programming. They just want to know what is tested, and if the tests fail or pass.

Comment: Well, I think it reads well. See an update for a more complete feature test.

Comment: I'm just now seeing that Roman wants to actually test the trimming of the spaces. In that case my comment is obsolete and your solution is indeed usefull!

Answer (score 0):

I just faced same situation, my solution was this, added spaces in the step as follows:

```
Scenario: Adding books with spaces in the title
Given the following book '    <title>    '
When book is saved
Then the title should be equals to '<title>'
| price | title        |
| 50.00 | Working hard |
```